# Does not fetch all products from db

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I currently downloaded MAMP on my mac and imported an SQL file containing 589 products with their own product_id. 
That worked fine and I can see all the products in "Browse".

I then tested the connection to this db. That worked aswell.

```
DEFINE('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DB_DATABASE', 'testproducts');

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error ('.mysqli_connect_errno().')'.mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully.';
```

I then tried to fetch all the products to see if that worked by creting a variable $num to see how many got fetched, but then I only get 295 products with this code:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ac_product");
$num = 0;
foreach ($res as $r) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$pid = $row['product_id'];
echo "</br>". $pid;
$num++;
}

echo "total: ".$num;

$mysqli->close();
```

Am I missing something from this? Thought this would just fetch all and not have a limit.

Anyone who have some knowledge of this? Thanks

Comment: You need a `while($row = $result->fetch_array($res))` I guess. Read through the user notes on [mysqli_fetch_array](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: @kerbholz Yeah, that worked. Or better while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)). Thanks